# How do I change the template of the login page in Magento?

Tags: xml, magento

for Magento

the page located at /customer/account/login/ is using 1column.phtml as its main template. Of course I know I can edit the login.phtml but thats not what I need. Thats already too deep. I need to switch the very first template file responsible for the looks of the login page. Which in my case is 1column.phtml. I want login page to use paul.phtml for example. How would I do that? Where do I assign a new template file to the login page specifically?

Answer (score 0):

just create your template file and assign it to customer login page at customer.xml.

```
<customer_account_login translate="label">
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/paul.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
</customer_account_login>
```